# I want to exclude specific domains in this code

Tags: php, api

This code is based on a shortcut all the links in the variable `$datatext`
I want to exclude specific domains from shortcut like `google.com|msn.com`

code :

```
<?php
$datatext = "bla bla bla bla <br /><a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.google.com</a><br /><br /><a href=\"http://www.msn.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.msn.com</a><br /><br /><a href=\"http://www.edaf.at\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.edaf.at</a> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla";
$wreplacer_first = 'target="_blank">www.';
$wreplacer_second = 'target="_blank">http://www.';
$data = str_replace("$wreplacer_first","$wreplacer_second",$datatext);
$reg_exUrl = "#\<a href=\"(.*)\" target=\"(.*)\"\>(.*)<\/a\>#Ui";

    preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $data, $matches);
    $links = $matches[1];

    foreach ($links as $val)
    { 
    $turl=$val;
      $link="http://v.gd/create.php?format=simple&url=".$turl."";
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
      $content = curl_exec($ch);  
      curl_close($ch);
      $datatext = str_replace($turl,"$content", $datatext);
      }
     echo $datatext;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to extract the domain from the URL, but you will need to also to an ends with a string check to see if it's the domain you. Since URLs could be for `www.google.com` or `drive.google.com` and such.

```
 function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
 {
     $length = strlen($needle);
     if ($length == 0) {
         return true;
     }
     return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
 }

$blacklist = array("google.com","msn.com");

foreach ($links as $val)
{ 
    $skip = false;
    foreach($blacklist as $domain)
    {
        if(endsWith(parse_url($val,PHP_URL_HOST),$domain))
        {
            $skip = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($skip) continue;
```